# Syntax Error when the column name contains underscore

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can compile but can't execute the following code
with the error (using Postgres):

```
Fatal database error
ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
Position: 13
```

---

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JDBCExample
{
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://hostname/database";
private static final String USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  Connection dbConn = null;
  Statement query = null;
  ResultSet results = null;

  Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

  try
  {
     dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
  }
  catch (SQLException e)
  {
     System.out.println("Unable to connect to database\n"+e.getMessage());
     System.exit(1);
  }

  try
  {
     query = dbConn.createStatement();
     results = query.executeQuery("select 20_5 as name from flowshop_optimums");

    while (results.next())
    {
      System.out.println(results.getString("name"));
    }

    dbConn.close();
  }
  catch (SQLException e)
  {
     System.out.println("Fatal database error\n"+e.getMessage());
     try
     {
        dbConn.close();
     }
     catch (SQLException x) {}
     System.exit(1);
  }

} // main

} // Example
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the underscore, it's the fact that the column name starts with a number. You'd need to escape this.

For MySQL, use backticks.

```
select `20_5` as name from flowshop_optimums
```

For SQL Server, use square brackets.

```
select [20_5] as name from flowshop_optimums
```

For PostgreSQL, use double quotes.

```
select "20_5" as name from flowshop_optimums
```

Comment: For backticks I get: Fatal database error ERROR: syntax error at or near "`" Position: 13. The same goes for brackets.

Comment: @Oleksandr: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Oleksandr: Use double quotes in that case.

Comment: This is what I get with double quotes (can't even compile):JDBCExample.java:49: ')' expected
         results = query.executeQuery("select "20_5" as name from flowshop_optimums");
                                               ^
JDBCExample.java:49: not a statement
         results = query.executeQuery("select "20_5" as name from flowshop_optimums");
                                                 ^
JDBCExample.java:49: ';' expected
         results = query.executeQuery("select "20_5" as name from flowshop_optimums");
                                                   ^
3 errors

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes within your double quoted string.

Comment: This brings me to the initial state.

Answer (score 2):

```
results = query.executeQuery("select \"20_5\" as name from flowshop_optimums");
```

But you should *really* change that column name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  results = query.executeQuery("select '20_5' as name from flowshop_optimums");

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't select named column but outputs 20_5 several times.

Comment: 20_5 is what you are selecting. If you want the name of the column to be 20_5 you need to "select 'some value' as 20_5 from flowshop_optimums".

Comment: I mean the column has name 20_5. And I want to select values from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose 20_5 with backticks or brackets, depending on whether or not you're using MySQL or SQLServer, respectively.