# Error: wrong syntax near '_1_txt'

Tags: c#, syntax

Unfortunately my Code does not work: It always throws the error: Wrong syntax near '_1_txt'. Thanks in advance!

This is my Code:

```
 protected void btnSpeichern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_mag(1_1_txt) VALUES(@1_1_txt)";
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1_1_txt", txt1.Text.Trim());

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your field name 1_1_txt??

Comment: column names may not start with a number (1_1_txt), or if this really is your field name, enclose in [])

Comment: Please read the MSDN docs about [valid identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe answered by this post:

[Syntax Error when the column name contains underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279898/syntax-error-when-the-column-name-contains-underscore)

Basically you have to Sql Escape the columns names by wrapping them in square brackets.

```
1_1_txt --> [1_1_txt]
```

Answer (score 1):

Column names generally shouldn't (or in some cases can't) begin with a number.  Ideally you should change your schema to follow this rule, but if you can't then at the very least you would need to explicitly specify the name as an identifier.  In SQL Server that's done with square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO [tbl_mag] ([1_1_txt]) VALUES (@1_1_txt)
```